# list of maps ,get values of a certain key and convert into a set in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have list of maps and need to get values of a certain key and put them into a set .

```
def listofMaps= [
    [1:"A", 2:"B", 3:"C", 4:"D"],
    [1:"E", 2:"F", 3:"G", 4:"H"],
    [1:"I", 2:"J", 3:"K", 4:"L"]]
```

i need to get values of key:'2' into a set??

how to do this in groovy in an easy way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go:

```
def maps= [[1:"A", 2:"B", 3:"C", 4:"D"],[1:"E", 2:"F", 3:"G", 4:"H"],[1:"I", 2:"J", 3:"K", 4:"L"]]

assert maps.collect {it[2]} as Set == ['B','F','J'] as Set
```

Comment: or `listofMaps*.get(2).toSet()`

Comment: Or `Set<String> result = listOfMaps*.get(2)`